# When I using jupyter notebook to train a model, the "ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments" existed

Tags: parsing, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, python-3.6

I'm learning to use jupyter notebook to train a model with Pytorch. But there exited a problem here when I run the cell. What should I do?
This is the code I think may existing problem.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch Training')
parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=1, type=int, metavar='BT',
                    help='batch size')
# =============== optimizer
parser.add_argument('--lr', '--learning_rate', default=1e-6, type=float,
                    metavar='LR', help='initial learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--momentum', default=0.9, type=float, metavar='M',
                    help='momentum')
parser.add_argument('--weight_decay', '--wd', default=2e-4, type=float,
                    metavar='W', help='default weight decay')
parser.add_argument('--stepsize', default=3, type=int, 
                    metavar='SS', help='learning rate step size')
parser.add_argument('--gamma', '--gm', default=0.1, type=float,
                    help='learning rate decay parameter: Gamma')
parser.add_argument('--maxepoch', default=30, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='number of total epochs to run')
parser.add_argument('--itersize', default=10, type=int,
                    metavar='IS', help='iter size')
# =============== misc
parser.add_argument('--start_epoch', default=0, type=int, metavar='N',
                    help='manual epoch number (useful on restarts)')
parser.add_argument('--print_freq', '-p', default=1000, type=int,
                    metavar='N', help='print frequency (default: 50)')
parser.add_argument('--gpu', default='0', type=str,
                    help='GPU ID')
parser.add_argument('--resume', default='', type=str, metavar='PATH',
                    help='path to latest checkpoint (default: none)')
parser.add_argument('--tmp', help='tmp folder', default='tmp/RCF')
# ================ dataset
parser.add_argument('--dataset', help='root folder of dataset', default='data/HED-BSDS_PASCAL')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

The error is :

```
"usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--batch_size BT] [--lr LR] [--momentum M]
                             [--weight_decay W] [--stepsize SS]
                             [--gamma GAMMA] [--maxepoch N] [--itersize IS]
                             [--start_epoch N] [--print_freq N] [--gpu GPU]
                             [--resume PATH] [--tmp TMP] [--dataset DATASET]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f C:\Users\59863\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-4a7fc5df-ea52-4c9e-93a9-f466074bfc90.json"
```

Answer (score 0):

`ArgumentParser.parse_args(args=None, namespace=None)` converts `args` (list of argument strings) to objects and assign them as attributes of the namespace.

If `args` is not provided, the default is taken from `sys.argv`. In your case, `sys.argv` is the arguments used to launch jupyter notebook.

So if you want to use `ArgumentParser` in jupyter notebook, pass in `args` manually:

```py
args = parser.parse_args(['--batch_size', '32']）
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally I add this sentence to solve the problem```args = parser.parse_args(args=[])```